# Awk - Writing length of subsequent line into line

Tags: string, awk

Assume a text file that comprises alternating lines. Specifically, line 1 of each line pair starts with a "#", whereas the subsequent line of each line pair contains an alphanumeric string.

```
$ cat file
#Foo
1234567
#Bar
1234
#Baz
123456789
```

How do I automatically append the length of line 2 (as well as a keyword) to line 1 of each line pair? I believe that `awk` is the right choice for such an operation.

```
$ awk 'desired code' file
#Foo_Length7
1234567
#Bar_Length4
1234
#Baz_Length9
123456789
```

Here's my try, but I can't figure out what to substitute the `length($0)` with:

```
awk '{if ($1~/^#/) print $0"_Length"length($0); else print $0}' file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '!(NR%2){print prev "_Length" length($0) ORS $0} {prev=$0}' file
#Foo_Length7
1234567
#Bar_Length4
1234
#Baz_Length9
123456789
```

You can replace `!(NR%2)` with `!/^#/` or similar if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk:

```
awk '{first=$0; getline; print first "_length" length($0); print}' file
```

Output:

```
#Foo_length7
1234567
#Bar_length4
1234
#Baz_length9
123456789
```

From `man awk`:

> `getline`: Set $0 from the next input record; set NF, NR, FNR, RT.

Comment: For more info on `getline` including when to use it and how to use it safely, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. Using `tac` + `awk` combination here. Written on mobile couldn't test it yet should work though.

```
tac Input_file | 
awk '
NR%2!=0{
  len=length($0)
  print
  next
}
{
  print $0"_Length"len
  len=""
}' | 
tac
```

***Explanation:*** Firstly using `tac` to print output in reverse  which will help us to deal with data manipulation easily. Then with awk every odd number of line printing it and taking its length in len variable. Then on every even line printing current line with length of previous line. Once awk is done with its processing then again using tac to reverse the Input_file to make it in actual format.