# AWK to divide line one and 2

Tags: bash, awk

After some grep and awk I have the following ouput.

```
 [root@nalba ~]# mysql -e "show global status like '%innodb_buffer_pool_read%';" | grep s | awk '{print $2}'

835231
2893
```

I simply want to divide 835231 / 2893.

However this numbers will change everytime the command is run so I just need to tell awk how to divide lines 1 and 2 or somehow store them in a variable.

Most tutorials online only show you dividing by the colunm. ( awk '{print $1 / $2) but that won't work in this case.

Thanks for stopping by!

Comment: Try piping with `tr -d '\n'` before `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append to your command:

```
| awk '{a=$1; getline; b=$1; print a/b}'
```

Update to avoid division by zero error:

```
| awk '{a=$1; getline; b=$1; if(b==0){print "error"} else {print a/b}}'
```

Output:

```
288.708
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed so I marked it as the correct answer, thanks a lot for your time, looks like the key here is the "getline" I will investigate more about it.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: See [Ed's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63604376/awk-writing-length-of-subsequent-line-into-line/63604439#comment112473134_63604439) for more informations about getline.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `| grep s | awk '{print $2}'` with:

```
| awk '/s/{v[++c]=$2} c==2{print (v[2] ? v[1] / v[2] : "NaN"); exit}'
```

Answer (score 1):

### Store Values in Array; Divide in End Block

If you know there will always be exactly two values, or you only care about the first two matches, then you can store the values in an associative array and perform your division at the end. For example:

```
test_data="foo 835231\nbar 2893"
echo -e "$test_data" |
    awk '{ values[NR] = $2 }; END { print values[1] / values[2] }'
```

This yields `288.708`.

If you're querying the database anyway, you might be better off constructing a SQL query that asks the database to perform the division for you. Never tinker with query results directly when you can get the database to do the work for you.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I was not able to understand your answer. Let me try to reprhase the question.
After this command I get two numbers, I just need to find a way to divide the two numbers because these numbers will always change.

 [root@nalba ~]# mysql -e "show global status like '%innodb_buffer_pool_read%';" | grep s | awk '{print $2}'

numbera
numberb

Comment: You could modify Todd's command to use it direct after your mysql command: `mysql ... | awk '/s/{ values[++c] = $2 }; END { print values[1] / values[2] }'`